# Showing all dates in google charts rather than only those returned in queries

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have a little problem that I've tried to fix in my JS / PHP with no luck.

Below is my code. The Google chart shows up perfectly on the page.

However, if the data in the DB is:

2017-06-18
2018-06-19
2017-06-21

I want to still show 2017-06-20 but with a value of zero.

At the moment, I end up with the below - as you can see 2017-06-20 is missing completely.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can make this work to show all dates?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

 ['Date', 'Total Orders'],
 <?php 
              $memberid = getLoggedMemberID();
 $query = "SELECT Order_Date as Order_Date1, sum(Discounted_Value) as id13chart FROM Orders 
  INNER JOIN membership_userrecords ON Orders.id = membership_userrecords.pkValue
where membership_userrecords.memberID = '$memberid' AND membership_userrecords.tableName='Orders' AND Order_Date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Order_Date ORDER BY Order_Date Asc";

 $exec = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

 echo "['".$row['Order_Date1']."',".$row['id13chart']."],";
 }
 ?>

 ]);

 var options = {
 title: 'Orders Per Day',
 colors: ['#2ab77e', '#545454'],
  is3D: true
 };
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("OrdersByDay"));
 chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: an easy way would be to convert the first column from string to date -- as shown in the answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44695692/5090771)...

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) for creating json date in php...

Comment: hmmm, im really struggling to get either of these to work with my code. When I make the changes, the whole page goes white. Perhaps I'm doing it incorrectly!

Comment: don't recommend mixing php and js in same file, try setting up like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)...